# DC-DC Boost Converter Only Works with a Second Supply

Tags: mosfet, pic, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm trying to build a 5V to 8V boost converter to use at another mosfet's gate voltage. I'm using a PIC mcu to create a 50kHz square wave signal to switch the BUZ101L. For test purposes i also added a potentiometer connected to an ADC channel which controls the duty cycle of square wave output.

When the PIC and potentiometer are connected to 5V supply from USB and DC-DC boost circuit is connected to seperate DC supply, it works like a charm. But when i try to connect them to the same DC supply, somehow it draws above 1.5A and doesnt work at all. What am i missing in here?

I thought the reason may be that DC-DC boost circuit saturates before PIC initializes when i supply them from same line. I tried connecting dc-dc boost part a while later then turning DC supply on. Didn't work.

[here are the pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ7L2.jpg)

Comment: Probably your cpu resets everytime the switch turns on because your power supply's current limit is exceeded. Also you dont have bypass caps on cpu supply and no input caps at your boost circuit. Also your Inductance is far too high for a proper boost converter (you should aim for current ripple ratio of .3 to .5, but thats another story. cant say more need more informations like voltage at cpu supply pin...

Comment: First of all, isn't the formula for minimum inductance is;

Lmin=  [(1-k)^2   * k*R] /  2*f

where  Vo/Vin = 1/1-k


with %37.5 duty cycle and 50kHz, minimum inductance seems like even more, like 1.46mH. Is there a guide or paper that i can follow for designing?